# Can I use my BENQ projector with a Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

I've got a [Benq W100 projector](http://www.projectorcentral.com/BenQ-W100.htm).

[image]

Is it possible to connect my Wii to this projector? How? What kind of cable do I need?

Many thanks in advance.

**Update**: I've uploaded [a picture of the projector](http://twitpic.com/3lmx1g).  I plugged the yellow cable of the Wii to the projector: now, I've got an image, but no sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

As your projector accepts components input, you will have to get [this cable](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000JJRV90) (or similar one from non-official brands).

But you could also use the provided Wii AV cable (yellow RCA for video and red/white for sound). Did you try and it doesn't work?

edit: For the sound part, you need "something" to ouput the sound coming from the wii. Either speakers with an adapter from the two RCA (white/red) to a jack plugged in the input of your speakers or a hifi sound system which will probably have a RCA input.  But you will not get the sound out of the projector which doesn't have sound input and speakers.

Comment: Thanks! I plugged the yellow cable to the projector (see http://twitpic.com/3lmx1g  ): It's better : now, I've got an image but no sound.

Comment: Check my edit for the sound part.

Comment: The component-cable (the one with the red, green and blue connectors) will give you a better image quality than the composite one (yellow connector). In either case you'll have to connect the red and white audio cables to your stereo or some speakers. If you're using a component cable, make sure to not mix up red for video and red for audio. Usually they are marked though.